# how to add an arraylist of objects to file

Tags: java

I want to write a program that have a sign up and sign in button. If the user press the sign up button then his username and password must be written to a file. I have a problem in appending to the file. I have an arraylist of object(user) called people, and I add this arraylist to my file. But when I print the contents of file I just see the first user, and if I print the arraylist, it has only one object that is the last one. Here is my addmethod in a class:

```
public class AddToFile 
{
    ArrayList<User> people = new ArrayList<User>();
    User user;

    public void add(String username, String password) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        User u1 = new User(username, password, "hello", null, null, null);

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("f.txt", true);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        people.add(u1);
        System.out.println(people.size());
        for (User people1 : people) 
        {
            System.out.println("user  " + people1.username + "  pass " + people1.password);
        }
        for (User p : people) 
        {
            out.writeObject(p);       
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("success");

        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("f.txt"));
        User u = (User) is.readObject();
        System.out.println("File  user :" + u.username + "    pass:" + u.password);
        is.close();       
    }    
}
```

That user is a class that implements serializable.

Comment: You're only reading the first object...

Comment: your are not allowed to append file when writing objects to it..better way to check is object file is present, if so then read the objects first and read it to `ArrayList<User>` and then add new `User` object to that array and finally write the same array to file...

Comment: how can I read all the objects of the file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple files for each objects (user) and keep in a directory with different file names. By using directory file name reader method, you can read back all files names in that directory. Then read each files and convert into user objects. I don't think append a object stream will work.

```
        ArrayList<User> people = new ArrayList<User>();
    User user;

    User u1 = new User(username, password, "hello", null, null, null);

    people.add(u1);
    System.out.println(people.size());
    for (User people1 : people) {
        System.out.println("user  " + people1.username + "  pass "
                + people1.password);
    }
    for (User p : people) {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("/tempObjects/"
                + p.getUserName(), true); // assume user name is unique
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        out.writeObject(p);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    System.out.println("success");

    File folder = new File("/tempObjects/"); //reading the folder
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); // all file names in that folder

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) { // reading each file details
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(listOfFiles[i].getName()));
            User u = (User) is.readObject();
            System.out.println("File  user :" + u.username + "    pass:"    + u.password);
            is.close();
        }
    }
```